# How to loop selected Month/Date/Year with 30 days interval in C#

Tags: c#, loops, datetimepicker

How to code this..

I selected `date` in `dateTimePicker` and I wanted to *loop* that with `24` months. Example

I selected

```
4/4/2018
5/4/2018
6/4/2018
7/4/2018
...
...
...
4/4/2020 (24 months)
```

Comment: What do you want to show if you pick 29th february?

Comment: `DateTime.AddDays(30)` should work for this unclear question. If you need nicer answer, try to write a nicer and more meaningful question.

Comment: `for (DateTime date = dateTimePicker.Value; date <= dateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(2); date = date.AddDays(30)) {...}`

Comment: @Fildor: It's a suggestion: the question wants `30` *days* interval while example uses `1` *month* one

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ah, I see. So there's an implicit request for clarification ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want a `for` *loop*, either with `30` days step (as in the *question's title*)

```
for (DateTime date = dateTimePicker.Value.Date; 
     date <= dateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(2); // or .AddMonths(24) 
     date = date.AddDays(30)) {
  ... 
}
```

or `1` month one (as in the *example* provided; since, say, `4th May` + `30` *days* is `3d June`, *not* `4th June`):

```
for (DateTime date = dateTimePicker.Value.Date; 
     date <= dateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(2); 
     date = date.AddMonths(1)) {
  ... 
}
```

Comment: @bree Mind that "30 days" and "1 month" _will_ produce different results! So if "30 days" is the common financial approximation to "1 Month" you should reconsider your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snipped:

```
DateTime dt = ... // Get the value from your Datetimepicker.
for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
    // do something, e.g. print the date; 
    dt= dt.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

list.Add(dt);

for (int i = 1 ; i < 24; i++)
{
    list.Add(dt.AddMonths(i));
}
```

In list , you will get all 24 dates as you asked in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddMonths method of DateTime class.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("4/4/2018");
var monthCount = 24;

while (monthCount-- > 0)
    dateTime = dateTime.AddMonths(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.AddMonths` Method and simple `for` loop:

```
 var date = new DateTime(2018, 4, 4); // use datetimepicker value instead
 for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 24; ctr++)
    Console.WriteLine(date.AddMonths(ctr).ToString("d"));
```